# SignIn in FirebaseAuth with idToken

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt

I want to have multiple logged accounts (with different auth providers Google,Apple, phone, email) in my app, so that the user can **switch between accounts**. To do that, I want to **store the idToken** and then use it to login without the need for the user to log in manually. I tried using this function:

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token);
```

But it returns this message:

> [firebase_auth/invalid-custom-token] The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

PS. I'm getting the idToken wih this function

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.getIdToken();
```

Image with the desired functionality

[image]

Thanks in advance!

I have tried storing the auth credentials but these have a short life time.
I expect to have tokens for different account, so I can switch this accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to do something else rather than use the idTokens. What I would suggest is to check the [providerId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredentialproviderid) when a user logs in and originally links the accounts. Store this providerId locally and then in your database for profiles, have a collection by the userId with documents segmented by the providerId and just retrieve it the profile by the chosen providerId. Another option would be to allow one users to generate multiple profiles freely but limit it to maybe 5 different accounts, this would simplify the ux since they won't need to generate multiple accounts for the same functionality.